# Divide and Conquer Heuristics for the Symmetric TSP

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-optimization

> **Question:**
>
> have there been serious attempts to design divide and conquer heuristics for generating near optimal Hamilton Cycles in complete symmetric graphs?

For clarification:

by a divide and conquer heuristic for TSP I mean

- recursively partitioning the set of vertices with minimal size difference (i.e. equal for even size and difference 1 for odd sizes),
  create at most two TSP from the partions until the instances can be optimally solved
- repeatedly creating a graph with a small number of Hamilton Cycles, e.g. a ladder graph, from the tours through both parts and return the Hamilton Cycle with optimal length.